# How do I chmod ACLs to groups with spaces in the name on Mac OS X?

Tags: mac-osx, access-control-list, chmod

I'm trying to add an ACL for the group "Domain Users", but since it has spaces in the group name it isn't parsed correctly by chmod:

```
$ chmod -R +a 'DOMAIN\Domain Users allow list,search,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit' shared
Unable to translate 'DOMAIN\Domain' to a UID/GID
```

How do I escape the space? I've tried all the obvious approaches with single quotes, double quotes, and backslash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Apple's [source for chmod](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/file_cmds/file_cmds-230/chmod/chmod_acl.c) is available, there's a hint in the parser:

```
if (strchr(pebuf, ':')) /* User/Group names can have spaces */
```

And indeed, if you read the man page it says:

> If the user or group name contains spaces you can use ':' as the
>   delimiter between name and permission.

Thus the solution is:

```
$ chmod +a 'DOMAIN\Domain Users:allow list,search,readattr,readextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit' shared
```